# How to directly detect the window position?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt-creator

I'm coding in c++ with Qt creator. I can get all windows on the screen but I would like to detect their movement directly. Is there any way to detect the movement thanks to a signal emitted by the window ?

Comment: *"all windows on the screen"* - what is that even supposed to mean?

Comment: all windows like the navigator, opened applications,....

Comment: Ok, in that case I'll challenge you to *"get all windows on the screen"*. Pretty sure that UIPI is going to be a pain to convince, that your low-integrity process should gain access to high-integrity resources. But anyway, you have a completely misguided understanding of your target platform. Qt does not emit any sorts of signals for windows, that do not even know Qt.

Answer (score -1):

You can try creating a QWindow from the target window and then wrap it in a QWidget using QWidget::createWindowContainer().

You can have a look at this QTBUG thread : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40320

It needs some effort to make it work properly. The captured window doesn't keep its initial dimensions, and releasing the window behave weirdly. Read the last QTBUG comments to find an improvement.

I added an event filter to this code to capture the window position in real time. But that might be unsatisfying.

```
class EventFilter : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
   EventFilter(){}
   virtual ~EventFilter(){}

protected:
     bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);
 } ;


bool EventFilter::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
   qDebug() << event->type() ;

    if (event->type() == QEvent::Move) {
        QMoveEvent *moveEvent = static_cast<QMoveEvent *>(event);
        qDebug() << "position" << moveEvent->pos() ;
        return true;
    } else {
        // standard event processing
        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
}
```

I removed part 3 from the QTBUG snippet and installed the event handler on the inner widget. You can also remove the timers.

```
// From https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40320
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    // Windows: Find HWND by window title
    WId id = (WId)FindWindow(NULL, L"Calculator");
    if (!id)
        return -1;

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    // Optional
    QTimer t;
    t.start(2500);

    // Part 1
    QWindow* window = QWindow::fromWinId(id);
    window->show();
    window->requestActivate();

    // Optional
    QObject::connect(&t, &QTimer::timeout, [=]
    {
        qDebug() << "=== Inner QWindow ===";
        qDebug() << "Geometry:" << window->geometry();
        qDebug() << "Active?:" << window->isActive();
        qDebug() << "Flags:" << window->flags();
    });

    // Part 2
    QWidget* widget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(window);
    widget->show();

    // Optional
    QObject::connect(&t, &QTimer::timeout, [=]
    {
        qDebug() << "=== Outer QWidget ===";
        qDebug() << "Geometry:" << widget->geometry();
        qDebug() << "Active?" << widget->isActiveWindow();
        qDebug() << "Flags:" << widget->windowFlags();
    });

    // Realtime position
    EventFilter filter ;
    widget->installEventFilter( &filter ) ;


    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
=== Inner QWindow ===
Geometry: QRect(0,0 640x480)
Active?: true
Flags: QFlags<Qt::WindowType>(ForeignWindow)
=== Outer QWidget ===
Geometry: QRect(2489,29 640x480)
Active? true
Flags: QFlags<Qt::WindowType>(Window|WindowTitleHint|WindowSystemMenuHint|WindowMinMaxButtonsHint|WindowCloseButtonHint)

QEvent::Type(Move)
position QPoint(2484,29)
QEvent::Type(Move)
position QPoint(2481,30)
QEvent::Type(Move)
position QPoint(2478,31)
QEvent::Type(Move)
position QPoint(2474,31)
```

See also http://blog.qt.io/blog/2013/02/19/introducing-qwidgetcreatewindowcontainer/

Comment: Fails to work across UIPI boundaries. And reaching out to a window owned by a different thread requires, that you know **exactly** what you are doing, and control the code in both threads for proper coöperation. You don't control the code in either thread. This **will** break.

Comment: P.S.: A robust solution uses [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373868.aspx).